# Using css to responsively resize the image and text inside a button tag

Tags: css, image, button, responsive

I have this:
.buttm{
    background: url('http://redshadow67.com/deepest/img/butts/divm.png') no-repeat center black;
    width: 100px; text-align: center; color: #f5c324; font-size: 18px; margin: 0 auto; border: 0px;
}

but I want to make the width between 60 and 100 depending on the viewscreen. When I use a percentage it doesn't resize the image, and also I need the text to be a little smaller also. Not sure what to do??? thanks

Comment: okay, I figured it out to style the button separate from the image, but how do I dynamically resize text too?

Comment: button{
    width: 20%; min-width: 60px; max-width: 100px; height: auto; padding: 4px; color: gold; font-weight: bold;
}

.butt{
    background: url('http://redshadow67.com/deepest/img/butts/divp.png') no-repeat center black;
    width: 100%; min-width: 60px; max-width: 100px;
}

Comment: this seems to work, for anybody who wants to know...though it doesn't address changing the font size into the bargain

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried media queries?

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  // Your custom styles go here.
}
```

Comment: I keep trying to figure @media out, but I end up with the fonts being either way too small or way too big. I got so fed up I went looking for other ways to make my page responsive instead.

Comment: Do you understand how media queries work? I recommend [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for  further reading.

Answer (score 0):

To scale the background-image, use the [`background-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). Try the values `contain` (full image shown) and `cover` (image scaled to fill entire element).

For width and font-size, use `@media` queries. You might also want to look into [viewport relative units](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/):

- `1vh`: 1% of viewport height
- `1vw`: 1% of viewport height
- `1vmin`: 1% of viewport height or width, whichever is smaller
- `1vmax`: 1% of viewport height or width, whichever is larger

Comment: I'm terrible at the @media thing and wanted something quick so I can keep working, so did what I know. Definitely am going to go look at background-size property though! thanks

Comment: I think the resized button works well though since I am trying to switch which image I put as the background in there. If I can just put the background resize into the button's code, I won't have to repeat it into each of the backgrounds.